# Is ReST a protocol? and is it only for web apps?

Tags: rest, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is RESTful/REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718204/what-is-restful-rest)

Is **ReST** a protocol? and is it only for web apps?

Comment: You should give this a read, by the way: [How I explained REST to my wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is less a protocol and more an... idea, if you like. It's a system of building a web service which follows a certain set of principles, making everything simple and easy to use.

Taking from the stack overflow tag for REST:

> Representational state transfer (REST) is a style of software
>   architecture for distributed hypermedia systems such as the World Wide
>   Web. It's more popular nowadays because of RESTful web services which
>   offers an alternate easier and simpler way for interoperability among
>   heterogeneous systems.

It revolves around giving everything you'd want to request an ID, and accessing it - rather than calling a service which performs a specific task, you access a specific ID or set of IDs. It means all actions can be standardised using basic HTTP methods such as `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc.

You can access a RESTful web service from anything, not just web apps.

But really, I could be here for quite a while explaining - as it's been said, the best thing you can do is just give it a Google and spend an hour or so reading. Perhaps [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) might be handy.

Answer (score 1):

No, its more like a design pattern applicable to client and server software. The clients and servers could use any protocol as long some form of hypertext messages are exchanged - no web or Internet required.

For more information, I'ld consult the Wikipedia definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer